# Handling a Default Null query on Supabase(react frontend)

Tags: react-hooks, supabase

I created a filter with useEffect, which queries results from a column with matching values. However, when the home page loads for the first time, there are no results - ideally there should be all values listed on the page until a filter is applied. I am unable to find the right info to modify my query:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchSmoothies = async () => {
    const { data, error } = await supabase
    .from('column10')
    .select('*')
    .eq('column_value', filterBy) ...}
```

I have a few lines or error handling and data handling if statemenets below this.
Should I be looking into other ways of applying the filter on the page?

I have searched for a way to modify my query and still use the same useEffect, but seems like im bad at writing queries - still learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this be something along the lines of what you are looking for?

```js
let query = supabase.from('table').select()

if(some condition) {
  query = query.eq('column_value', filterBy)
}

if(other conditions) {
  query = query.lt('created_at', someDateValue)
}

const { data, error } = await query;
```